# log4net across appdomains

Tags: log4net, appdomain

I have an application which initializes log4net from one appdomain and needs to use it in another appdomain. Is it supported?

If not, should I initialize log4net from each appdomain? Is there a risk in multiple initializations in the same application? Should I use the same log4net.config?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [log4net-user](http://www.mail-archive.com/log4net-user@logging.apache.org/msg02875.html) mailing list has an answer that works with RollingFileAppender. Add the following line to the appender in log4net.config:

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

Comment: What about rollover? Is it still safe when potentially done from different app domains?

Answer (score 9):

Although the question is several years old - maybe it helps someone:

It is possible to use the loggers configured in the parent AppDomain. 
What needs to be done is route the `LoggingEvent`s from the child AppDomain to the parent AppDomain. For this you need to create a custom Appender that forwards the records out of the Child domain...

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents an <see cref="IAppender"/> implementation that forwards a <see cref="LoggingEvent"/> to a given Receiver.
/// Instances of this class should be created in the child domain.
/// </summary>
public class CrossDomainOutboundAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
    private readonly CrossDomainParentAppender crossDomainParentAppender;
    public CrossDomainOutboundAppender(CrossDomainParentAppender crossDomainParentAppender)
    {
        if (crossDomainParentAppender == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("crossDomainParentAppender");
        }
        this.crossDomainParentAppender = crossDomainParentAppender;

    }

    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        LoggingEvent copied = new LoggingEvent(loggingEvent.GetLoggingEventData());
        crossDomainParentAppender.Append(copied);
    }
}
```

, a custom class that receives the forwarded LoggingEvent and appends them to available `IAppender`s ...

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a Receiver that sends Log4Nets <see cref="LoggingEvent"/> to all available <see cref="IAppender"/>s.
/// Instances of this class should be created in the ParentDomain.
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public class CrossDomainParentAppender : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        foreach (IAppender usedAppender in LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders())
        {
            usedAppender.DoAppend(loggingEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

and finally a setup class that ties the two and configures log4net:

```
public class CrossDomainChildLoggingSetup : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private CrossDomainParentAppender parentAppender;

    public void ConfigureAppender(CrossDomainParentAppender crossDomainParentAppender)
    {
       parentAppender = crossDomainParentAppender;
       CrossDomainOutboundAppender outboundAppender = new CrossDomainOutboundAppender(parentAppender);
       log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(outboundAppender);
    }
}
```

Now - when you setup up your AppDomain you can add the following code...

```
CrossDomainParentAppender crossDomainParentAppender = new CrossDomainParentAppender();
Type crossDomainType = typeof(CrossDomainChildLoggingSetup);
CrossDomainChildLoggingSetup crossDomainChildLoggingSetup = (CrossDomainChildLoggingSetup)domain.CreateInstanceFrom(crossDomainType.Assembly.Location, crossDomainType.FullName).Unwrap();
crossDomainChildLoggingSetup.ConfigureAppender(crossDomainParentAppender);
```

...and everything logged in the child domain turns up in the parent domains log. 
(Please note: I used `CreateInstaceFrom(assemblyFilePath,...)` - depending on your setup you may not require loading by filePath)

Although I haven't found any bugs or problems: If you see any flaws or problems that could arise please let me know.

Comment: Exactly the type of approach I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: If I may suggest an improvement - instead of BasicConfigurator.Configure(outputAppender), changing to the following to pick up the parent domain configuration: var hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(outboundAppender);
hierarchy.Configured = true;

Comment: Have you gotten a RemotingException when using this? I will get an exception saying "Object '/a0720457_c9e6_4edf_bde5_86d96058cb4e/+mauuadzzsfpiaad3bjv4uss_264.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server." which I believe is because of garbage collection. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I didn't run into it, but it should be possible. To circumvent this problem, it would be possible to implement a keep alive handling and periodically ping the remote object.

Comment: I figured it out. I overrode CrossDomainChildLoggingSetup.InitializeLifetimeService to return null since there's only one per app domain and gets cleaned up when the AppDomain is unloaded. I then implemented ISponsor to handle the lifetime of the CrossDomainParentAppender, and used this code to initialize it:

var sponsor = new MySponsor(this, k);
var lease = (ILease)RemotingServices.GetLifetimeService(crossDomainParentAppender);
lease.Register(sponsor);

Comment: This is great but seem to loose the method name in the logs, just shows ? instead

Answer (score 5):

The logger should be initialized once per app-domain.

Comment: Would it not cause lock issues when two loggers try to append to the same file?

Answer (score 3):

Agree with darin, once per app domain. If you're looking to have these applications use consolidated logging, you'll want to choose a logging target that won't be subject to contention (i.e. not FileAppender or RollingFileAppender).

Answer (score 1):

My answer adds to Linky 's answer.

To answer, Jack Allan 's question. You can solve this by solving the changing the CrossDomainOutboundAppender class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents an <see cref="IAppender"/> implementation that forwards a <see cref="LoggingEvent"/> to a given Receiver.
/// Instances of this class should be created in the child domain.
/// </summary>
public class CrossDomainOutboundAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
    private readonly CrossDomainParentAppender crossDomainParentAppender;
    public CrossDomainOutboundAppender(CrossDomainParentAppender crossDomainParentAppender)
    {
        if (crossDomainParentAppender == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("crossDomainParentAppender");
        }
        this.crossDomainParentAppender = crossDomainParentAppender;

    }

    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        LoggingEvent copied = new LoggingEvent(loggingEvent.GetLoggingEventData(FixFlags.All));
        crossDomainParentAppender.Append(copied);
    }
}
```

Notice the FixFlags.All

The current version of the .... has a flaw causing all appenders to log the message, thats like defeating the purpose of log4net, since different loggers can log at a different level for example. My improved version of the class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a Receiver that sends Log4Nets <see cref="LoggingEvent"/> to all available <see cref="IAppender"/>s.
/// Instances of this class should be created in the ParentDomain.
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public class CrossDomainParentAppender : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        LogManager.GetRepository().Log(loggingEvent);
    }
}
```

This distributes the log to the logmanager, this will find out where to place the log, which logger is responsible etc.